# Separating nested list and dictionary in separate columns

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I created an function to gather the following sample list below:

```
full_list = ['Group1', [{'a':'1', 'b':'2'},{'c':'3', 'x':'1'}]
            'Group2', [{'d':'7', 'e':'18'}],
            'Group3', [{'m':'21'}, {'n':'44','p':'13'}]]
```

As you can see some of the elements inside the lists are made up of key-value pair dictionaries. 
And these dictionaries are of different sizes (number of kv pairs).
Can anyone suggest what to use in python to display this list in separate columns?

```
      Group1                    Group2                Group3                  
      {'a':'1', 'b':'2'}    {'d':'7', 'e':'18'}     {'m':'21'}      
      {'c':'3', 'x':'1'}                            {'n':'44','p':'13'}
```

I am not after a solution but rather a point in the right direction for a novice like me.
I have briefly looked at itertools and pandas dataframes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

First extract the columns and the data:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = full_list[::2]
#['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3']

data = full_list[1::2]
#[[{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, {'c': '3', 'x': '1'}],
# [{'d': '7', 'e': '18'}],
# [{'m': '21'}, {'n': '44', 'p': '13'}]]
```

Here the `[::2]` means iterate from begin to end but only every 2 items and so does `[1::2]` but it starts iterating from index `1` (second position)

Then create a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#0  {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}    {'c': '3', 'x': '1'}
#1  {'d': '7', 'e': '18'}   None
#2  {'m': '21'}     {'n': '44', 'p': '13'}
```

Ooops but the columns and rows are transposed so we need to convert it:

```
df = df.T
```

Then add the columns:

```
df.columns = columns
```

And there we have it:

```
     Group1                 Group2                  Group3
0   {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}    {'d': '7', 'e': '18'}   {'m': '21'}
1   {'c': '3', 'x': '1'}    None                    {'n': '44', 'p': '13'}
```